# Explain why this system of sets is the minimal ring generated by a semiring $\mathscr{S}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Theorem:** If $\mathscr{S}$ is a semiring, then
>   $\mathscr{R}(\mathscr{S})$ coincides with the system $\mathscr{L}$ of
>   all sets $A$ which have finite expansions $$A = \cup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}$$
>   with respect to the sets $A_k \in \mathscr{S}$

In the proof of this theorem in my book, they show why $\mathscr{L}$ is a ring which I understand. However, they then say

> The fact that $\mathscr{L}$ is a *minimal* ring generated by
>   $\mathscr{S}$ is obvious

but embarrassingly this is not obvious to me. I suspect it is "obvious" because it is supposed to come directly from the definition of a minimal ring, but I don't see it.

Could someone explain to me as elementary as possible why the set $\mathscr{L}$ is indeed the minimal ring? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $\mathscr{L}$ is a ring, and it is clear that $\mathscr{L}$ contains every $A \in \mathscr{S}$. That is, $\mathscr{L}$ is a ring containing $\mathscr{S}$, i.e $\mathscr{L} \supseteq \mathscr{S}$.

$\mathscr{L}$ is a *minimal* ring just in case it is contained in every other ring containing $\mathscr{S}$. Let $\mathscr{L}'$ be any other ring containing $\mathscr{S}$. We must show that $\mathscr{L} \subseteq \mathscr{L}'$.

If $A \in \mathscr{L}$, then $A = \cup_{k=1}^n A_k$ and $A_k \in \mathscr{S}$. Since $\mathscr{L}'$ contains $\mathscr{S}$, $A_k \in \mathscr{L}'$ as well. Since $\mathscr{L}'$ is a ring it is closed under finite unions, thus $A \in \mathscr{L}'$. Therefore, $\mathscr{L} \subseteq \mathscr{L}'$, as desired.